# Is the charge involved in electromagnetic wave propagation the same charge associated with electrons?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, electrons

This may be a naive question. My understanding is that there are fields that are involved with light and other E/M waves propagating but as far as I know, there are no electrons directly involved. If there are no electrons involved, where does this charge come from? Also, could a positive charge, like the one associated with protons, cause something like waves to propagate?

Comment: A propagating electromagnetic wave doesn't *have* any charge in it.

Comment: @Chris: aren't their fields involved?

Comment: Yes, electromagnetic fields. Electromagnetic fields aren't made of charge, though. Charges make electromagnetic fields, but once they're made they are happy to just propagate on their own.

Comment: are you saying that the electromagnetic field made by the charge of an electron is not negative or positive?

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to call an EM wave "positive" or "negative," no.

Comment: @Chris: Well, I think that answers my question.

Comment: @Chris: I was not referring to the wave but to the field and I have a reference that does indeed discuss negative and positive fields.

Comment: That's odd nomenclature. The field is a vector quantity at every point: it has an (always positive) magnitude and a direction. You can define one direction as positive and one as negative along each axis, but that doesn't make the field intrinsically positive or negative.

Comment: https://www.princeton.edu/ssp/joseph-henry-project/eddy-currents/A-students-guide-to-maxwells-equations-D.-FleischLEISC.pdf is reference. Diagram on page 4.

Comment: Doesn't say the fields are negative or positive. It shows the fields *around* positive and negative charges.